# Visualforce StandardController Event based on PageLayouts

Tags: standardcontroller

There is a way to create a dynamic visualforce page and render the fields depends of the page layout?. Now I have 2 page layouts with different fields and I won't to create two visualforces. I'm creating this page because visualforce is not visible in the standard edit mode page of my recodrs.

Greats

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you can get the current layout directly but since the page layout is determined by record type and current user's profile and you can definitely adjust your VF page based on those two values. This is not the perfect solution since once you changed your page layout assignment you will have to change your code but will solve your issue. And the maintenance shouldn't be too bad though.